# my android app is not showing in settings > accounts

Tags: android, synchronization, user-accounts

I have made an app which is responsible to synchronize data on server, but when I use preferences settings to set sync time in the list my app is not showing.
in the list there is : dropbox, linkedIn, skype, whatsApp, Email, etc but my App is not in the list.
what should I do to make it on the list of preferences settings and also it is not showing in settings > accouts.
    Thanks

Comment: Well I never did something with accounts but maybe your app needs a permission or a special intent filter, something that has to do with MANAGE_ACCOUNTS maybe?

Comment: Please post your code and screenshot